# prevent shortClick when longClick pressed

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

I want to cancel shortClick when LongClicked an item,
I'm using [ripple effect  material-ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) library in list view but when i long press list item it also call onClick-event

list.setOnItemClickListner not work with MaterialRippleLayout on row item

i have also return true in OnLongClicked but does not work..

also tried and added method in [MaterialRippleLayout.java](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/balysv/materialripple/MaterialRippleLayout.java#L159)

```
   @Override
   public void setOnLongClickListener(OnLongClickListener l) {
    super.setOnLongClickListener(l);
     childView.setOnLongClickListener(l);
}
```

and some changes in [gesturedetectore](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/balysv/materialripple/MaterialRippleLayout.java#L275)

here is my code list_item

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center" >

<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item_ripple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    app:rippleAlpha="0.2"
    app:rippleColor="#585858"
    app:rippleDelayClick="true"
    app:rippleHover="true"
    app:rippleOverlay="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Name/Number"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2_dur"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Duration"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3_in_out"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Incoming/Outgoing"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

& java code

```
      holder.riple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item riple clicked "+position, 0).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("songs", list_path.get(position).toString());
                    intent.putExtra("name", ""+parts[0]);
                    intent.putExtra("dur", ""+convertMillis(parts[2]));
                    intent.putExtra("time", getDate(parts[1].toString()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.riple.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    list.showContextMenu();
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LongClick", 0).show();
                    //v.setClickable(false);//v.isClickable();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

sory for bad english

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a `ListView` and `list_item` is the xml for each row. If I'm wrong, stop reading now! But if I'm right, we should consider using the methods `setItemClickListener()` and `setOnItemLongClickListener()`.

So in your `Activity`:

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            return true; // return true to prevent the `onClick` from being triggered as well.
        }
    });
```

Notice the position parameter gets passed in these two methods, so as long as you have a reference to the data set that is being displayed, you can access the exact item that was clicked or long clicked.

It's hard for me to tell why your code wasn't working, so some might not consider this an answer, but I hope this can help. All I know is that things can get really messy when setting click listeners on individual views inside a list view through the adapter.

As a side note, if the only action we want to execute in the on long click action is showing the context menu, then we should consider using `registerForContextMenu(listView)` and then using the context menu life cycle. [One can find more documentation on that practice here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: sorry for i didnt mention that, but listView.setOnItemClickListner not work for me, if i remove MaterialRippleLayout from xml than itemClick.. works fine... with ripple effect itemClick not works

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a [bug in material-ripple library](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple/issues/15)  , already reported there,https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple/issues/15

i have solved my issue,

boolean isLongClick = false;

```
    holder.riple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item riple clicked "+position, 0).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("songs", list_path.get(position).toString());
                intent.putExtra("name", ""+parts[0]);
                intent.putExtra("dur", ""+convertMillis(parts[2]));
                intent.putExtra("time", getDate(parts[1].toString()));
                if(isLongClick== false)
                {
                startActivity(intent);
                }
                 // for click agin on item
                isLongClick = false;
            }
        });
        holder.riple.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                isLongClick = true;
                list.showContextMenu();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LongClick", 0).show();
                //v.setClickable(false);//v.isClickable();
                return true;
            }
        });
```