# Checkbox state in listview onItemLongClick

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in which when you select a row, it's checkbox becomes checked / unchecked. However, I have a `onItemLongClick` that displays a dialog.

Problem is when I long-click a row in the listview, it becomes checked and I don't want that to happen, I just need it to display a dialog. This is confusing me because the `onItemClick` is also called when I use `onItemLongClick`.

> Here's the code for `onItemClick`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
            String shitts = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            try {
                checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
                String[] a = shitts.split(", ");
                String[] sep = a[0].split("=");
                String betamount = sep[1];
                String[] sepx = a[2].split("=");
                String betnumber = sepx[1];
                String showbetnumber = betnumber.replaceAll("[;/:*?\"<>|&{}']","");

                if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                    hash.put(showbetnumber,tv3.getText().toString());
                }else {
                    tv3.setText(betamount);
                    checked.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(position));
                    hash.remove(showbetnumber,tv3.getText().toString());
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
    });
```

> and here's the code for `onItemLongClick`

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView txAmt = view.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Enter Amount:");
            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String x = input.getText().toString();
                    txAmt.setText(x);
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //Put actions for CANCEL button here, or leave in blank
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Implement it in adapter.

Comment: Change the last line of your onItemLongClick from `return false` to `return  true`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean `isLongClick` and set it to `false`.

`onItemLongClick()`, set `isLongClick` to `true`.

On your dialog, set `isLongClick` to `false` again when any button is clicked or if the dialog was dismissed.

Finally, wrap all your code inside `onItemClick()` in:

```
if (!isLongClick) { 
    // onItemClick() code
}
```

[The source of this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374594/prevent-shortclick-when-longclick-pressed/27378010#27378010)